# How can I use query match AND instead of comma?

Tags: database, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I have a 3 columns "why, target,rate,similarto" . This is a kind of recommendation system . target is "A Hotel", similarto is "B Hotel, C Hotel" why is reason . if "why" column have "Antalya,Kum Plaj", my result MUST include "Antalya,Kum Plaj" together like "Antalya AND Kum Plaj" when you look at below picture, you can see that "Antalya,Kum Plaj" working as "Antalya OR Kum Plaj".

I tried 2 queries but both of them not working properly.

My first query:

```
    {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "rate": {
              "gte": 0.7,
              "lte": 1,
              "boost": 2.0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "target.keyword": "Robinson Club Nobilis"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "why": "Antalya,Kum Plaj"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
    
  }
}
```

Second query:

```
    POST /hotelsimilaritydeneme*/_search
{
   "query":{
      "multi_match" : {
         "query": "(Kum Plaj AND Antalya) and Not why.keyword : '' and target.keyword :'Design Plus Seya Beach'  and rate >= 0.6",
         "fields": [ "why","target","rate"]
      }
   }
}
```

I am not confusing but the result should include " Kum plaj,Antalya" .but some result has only "kum plaj" sum result "Antalya" of course another hotel feature exists. But "Kum Plaj , antalya" should work "Kum Plaj AND Antalya" not "Kum Plaj Or Antalya"

This is my mapping:

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "object": {
      "properties": {
        "rate": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "similarTo": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "target": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "why": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My Sample data :

```
{
  "took": 98,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 17,
    "max_score": 10.760553,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "xxx-2020",
        "_type": "object",
        "_id": "nuy9cnMBwlYcZ3X2cH4o",
        "_score": 10.760553,
        "_source": {
          "target": "Robinson Club Nobilis",
          "similarTo": "Crystal Waterworld Resort & Spa",
          "rate": 0.75,
          "why": "Diyet Büfesi,Kum Plaj,Antalya"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "xxx-2020",
        "_type": "object",
        "_id": "yuy9cnMBwlYcZ3X2cH4o",
        "_score": 10.760553,
        "_source": {
          "target": "Robinson Club Nobilis",
          "similarTo": "Crystal Sunset Luxury Resort & Spa",
          "rate": 0.75,
          "why": "Diyet Büfesi,Kum Plaj,Antalya"
        }
      }]
      }
}
```

Comment: It is a value. Why the confusion between AND OR? Could you explain bit more?

Comment: I am not confusing but the result should include " Kum plaj,Antalya" .but some result has only "kum plaj" sum result "Antalya" of course another hotel feature exists. But "Kum Plaj , antalya" should work "Kum Plaj AND Antalya" not "Kum Plaj Or Antalya"

Comment: Are you saying that single `why` column has comma separated values? `why:a, b`? Can you add mapping for `why` also?

Comment: Also Can you add a sample document with why fields which has both values

Comment: @gaurav9620 , I updated my question after your comments. thank you again.

Comment: @Gibbs ,  I added my map in my question after your comments. thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works as per the mapping. Because `text` uses `standard` analyzer. Hence your terms will be tokenised as

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "kum",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 3,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "plaj",
            "start_offset": 4,
            "end_offset": 8,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "antalya",
            "start_offset": 9,
            "end_offset": 16,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

So, `Antalya` alone documents are part of the results.

To avoid this, you need to change the mapping.

I suggest you to use comma separated [patternTokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-analyzer.html) along with [standard filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/analysis-standard-tokenfilter.html)

To achieve with the same mapping:

```
{
  "query":{
    "query_string":{
      "fields":["why"],
      "query": "Kum Plaj, Antalya",
      "default_operator":"and"
    }
  }
}
```

Documents - output:

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "similar",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "aafzvXMBoP4Sw8kfTdzk",
        "_score": 0.7161402,
        "_source": {
          "target": "Robinson Club Nobilis",
          "similarTo": "Crystal Waterworld Resort & Spa",
          "rate": 0.75,
          "why": "Diyet Büfesi,Kum Plaj,Antalya"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "similar",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "aqfzvXMBoP4Sw8kfctxi",
        "_score": 0.7161402,
        "_source": {
          "target": "Robinson Club Nobilis",
          "similarTo": "Crystal Sunset Luxury Resort & Spa",
          "rate": 0.75,
          "why": "Diyet Büfesi,Kum Plaj,Antalya"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Input docs:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "similar",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "aafzvXMBoP4Sw8kfTdzk",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "target": "Robinson Club Nobilis",
          "similarTo": "Crystal Waterworld Resort & Spa",
          "rate": 0.75,
          "why": "Diyet Büfesi,Kum Plaj,Antalya"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "similar",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "aqfzvXMBoP4Sw8kfctxi",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "target": "Robinson Club Nobilis",
          "similarTo": "Crystal Sunset Luxury Resort & Spa",
          "rate": 0.75,
          "why": "Diyet Büfesi,Kum Plaj,Antalya"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "similar",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "a6f1vXMBoP4Sw8kfrNyB",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "target": "Robinson Club Nobilis",
          "similarTo": "Crystal Sunset Luxury Resort & Spa",
          "rate": 0.75,
          "why": "Diyet Büfesi,Kum Plaj"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I have tons of rows.It is not end of the world but  I can not change anything. I need something like :  {
          "match": {
            "why": "Antalya,Kum Plaj", operation : {"AND"}
          }

Comment: thank you. I am really thirsty for your new updated reply.